# Function called Path in Python

Tags: python, path, python-import

I am reviewing a Python tutorial and having difficulties with this line of code:

```
csv_path = Path('../Documents/test.csv')
```

I could not find a function called 'Path' after a search online. Can anyone explain what this might be?

Comment: It's not actually a function. It's a class called [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path).

Comment: A bizarre number of "functions" in Python are actually classes

Comment: I see, thank you guys. It looked like a function, worked like a function so I thought...

Comment: There is a convention in Python (see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) ) to use only lowercase for functions, and CapWords for classes, it helps to guess which is which.

Comment: Ahh, that is very helpful, did not know that!!! Highly appreciate it, that will avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That convention is often ignored though. `str` along with the getters in `operator` are classes despite their name. The convention is really only useful for PEP8 compliant non-builtin code.

Comment: Ah of course. Good to know though, thank you for pointing that out. Should not blindly rely on that.

Answer (score 4):

It comes from the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)  module of the standard library

```
from pathlib import Path
```